# TestKit for Erlang

Tags: testing, erlang

Is there any kind of test framework for Erlang which is similar to [TestKit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#Asynchronous_Integration_Testing_with_TestKit) in Akka?

The goal is to test processes in an integrated environment, for example, to send some messages to a group of processes on one end and assert the resulting messages coming out on the other end. The Akka Testkit makes these kinds of tests fairly straightforward, but I have not been able to find the equivalent in Erlang yet.

EDIT: as the simplest example of what I'm looking for, let's say that we have a process A that is expected to send a message to process B, and I would like to test this behaviour.

In Akka, I can instantiate an actor based on the TestKit class, which has a builtin method `expectMsg`. So my test looks like this:

- instantiate a mock B actor
- instantiate the A actor (which gets a reference to B somehow)
- send B a message
- call B.expectMsg to verify that it received the message (note that

  - this automatically makes sure that no other type of message is sent to B, and
  - you can optionally provide a timeout)

Is there a library that supports this kind of workflow in Erlang? As far as I know neither EUnit nor CT support this kind of testing.

To get an idea of the more complex assertions, please see this page: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/testkit/TestKit.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erlang itself makes these kinds of tests fairly straightforward. There is [Lightweight Unit Testing Framework for Erlang `eunit`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html) and there is [Common Test](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/users_guide.html) framework for high scale integration testing.

**Edit**:
You don't need nothing more than Erlang for such simple things:

```
$ cat echo.erl 
-module(echo).

-export([start/0, send/3]).

start() ->
    spawn_link(fun() ->
                      receive
                          {To, Msg} -> To ! Msg
                      end
              end).

send(Echo, To, Msg) ->
    Echo ! {To, Msg}.

-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

echo_test_() ->
    Msg =  "Hello world!",
    {timeout, 0.1, fun() ->
                           Echo = echo:start(),
                           echo:send(Echo, self(), Msg),
                           ?assertEqual(Msg, receive X -> X end)
                   end}.
$ erlc echo.erl 
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
1> eunit:test(echo, [verbose]).
======================== EUnit ========================
echo: echo_test_ (module 'echo')...ok
=======================================================
  Test passed.
ok
2>
```

Process `A` is started by `echo:start/0` and process `B` is testing process itself. If you want mock existing modules there is [`meck`](http://eproxus.github.io/meck/). If you would like just watch messages between two processes without messing with receiver code, you can of course use tracing capabilities of Erlang VM itself.

Comment: Please can you take a look at my updated question, maybe the original was too vague...